# How to use shared resource file between projects in one solution?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, embedded-resource, solution-explorer

I have a problem with resource files.

I have a solution with two projects. The first project contains `ImageResource.resx` file with the images that I use. Every `Form` in this project can access this file from the designer. But I can see in the designer `ImageResource.resx` file to use it from second project (*Reference to second project is present*).

I have added the `ImageResource.resx` file as a link to my second project. And I saw it in the designer! But when I use an image from this resource in the second project Visual Studio modified my original file *(It sets the namespaces, and other..)* and my solution breaks. Also Visual Studio tells me that `ImageResource.resx` is present in two dll's `first_project.dll` and `second_project.dll`

Can anybody help me with **How to correctly use shared resources between projects?**

Answer (score 42, accepted):

1. The correct way to share resources is to create a global shared project. Create a new Project with the name *Resources*:

[image: Solution Explorer, showing an example solution, which contains a project named *Resources*]

2. Next we must add some resources (such as icons) to the project. Do this as usual. Go to the projects setting, select tab *Resources* and *Add Existing File…* to the project. We can see that the icon is added to the project and was copied to the local folder:

[image: For example, the Resources project's Resources tab shows a picture of a puppy, and the Solution Explorer shows that the Resources project's Resources folder includes the picture of the puppy]

3. Next step consists of adding this icon to the other project(s). Note the important difference, you need to add this icon as a **link**!

   Adding as a link avoids the resource duplication. Create a new Project within the same solution and name it e.g. *Main*. Create some folder in this new project, naming it *Resources* (the logical name for our purpose). Then right click on this folder, select *Add Existing Item…* and choose the image file from the shared project folder. Make sure to use **Add As Link** here! If done correctly the icon of the newly added file will look slightly different (see below):

[image: In the *Add Existing Item* dialog, choose the *Add As Link* option from the *Add* button's drop-down list]

Added resource's icon must look like this

[image: In Solution Explorer, the Main project's icon for the puppy Resource has an arrow on the icon, whereas the Resources project's icon for the puppy Resource does not have an arrow on the icon]

4. Now we must set the *Build Action* for this file to ***None***. For this select the file and go to the *Properties* Window. There choose *None* for *Build Action*. We need to do this to avoid embedding this icon into the assembly:

[image: In Solution Explorer, change the *Main* project's puppy resource's properties. Choose a Build Action of *None*]

5. Finally we need to add the linked files to the *Resources* of the corresponding project. Open the project *Properties* for the project where we just added the files. Choose the *Resource* tab and drag the linked file there:

[image: Drag the linked image from the Solution Explorer's *Main* project's resources to the *Main* project's resources tab's viewing pane]

These are the five simple steps you must perform to share icons between projects. You might ask "What are the benefits of this?" The benefits are:

- We store resources in one place, and
- It is easy to replace an icon with a new one.

Comment: This answer seems to be missing some text?

Comment: Allow me to ask "What is the benefits of this?" :-)

Comment: We store resources in one place and it is easy to replace some icon with new one.

Answer (score 3):

This didn't work for me and I found another (VS2015+) approach. 
 See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45471284/4151626

In short, the shared project is directly included into the peripheral project.  Thus, even though the IDE does not support `<Resource>` elements in the shared project.  `<Resource>` elements can be added to the shared project, via a text editor.  They are then incorporated into the peripheral project during the build.

*(Apologies for the hyper-link.  I would just repost the answer for clarity, but the stackoverflow editors crack down on this, deleting duplicate answers to save you from ???.)*

Comment: What didn't work for you?   (referring to the very first sentance)

Comment: @StayOnTarget, At the time, binary resources like icons and and graphic images had no UI support for sharing between projects.  But, with a little bit of text editing and a lack of directory support, binary resources could be shared!

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a symbolic link to share the file into multiple folders?

windows:

```
mklink linked_location\ImageResource.resx original_location\ImageResource.resx


C:\Users\preet>mklink
Creates a symbolic link.

MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target

        /D      Creates a directory symbolic link.  Default is a file
                symbolic link.
        /H      Creates a hard link instead of a symbolic link.
        /J      Creates a Directory Junction.
        Link    specifies the new symbolic link name.
        Target  specifies the path (relative or absolute) that the new link
                refers to.
```

Answer (score 1):

If a resource file is really shared between projects, you should put it in a shared project.

```
Solution 'Sample'
   Project Sample.Data
   Project Sample.Business
   Project Sample.UI
   Project Sample.Resource   //shared resources are put in a shared project
```

Comment: Project has the same structure what you say. The problem is that I can't see `Project Sample.Resource.ImageResource.resx` in `Project Sample.UI` in the designer. I must go to the `myForm.designer.cs` and manually types `button.Image = Sample.Resource.ImageResource.SomeImage`.. And later when VS reconstruct `myForm.designer.cs` line where I types an image for a button will be `button.Image = ( (System.Drawing.Image)( resources.GetObject( "SomeImage.Image" ) ) );` And VS automatically insert (copying) from ImageResource.resx file SomeImage into resource file for specific form.. :(

Comment: @Yuriy: The link is broken(maybe because I'm in China and some websites are blocked by the government). And more about my answer, I think you have some options incorrectly set(but sorry I don't remember more details about the settings), I once worked on a project, which shares its resources between a few projects just like your solution. We programmers use such a way like what I said in my answer and it really works.

Answer (score 0):

You can't see the resource if it is not **public**, and it is default set to "Friend". You can set the "Access Modifier" in the Visual Designer (upper right-hand corner).