# How to properly access localized resources in another project which my project depends on

Tags: c#, visual-studio, localization, resx

The first and second question are solved. I keep them for being a reference for the unsolved third question.

#### Original Question

**Original title**: Cannot create a resource designer and access resource strings with different locales?
I want to localize my project and some problems came up.
My current resource files are like this:
[image: 2.png]
The values(Just for testing):
In `Resources.resx`:
[image: 5.png]
In `Resources.zh-CN.resx`:
[image: 6.png]

### First Question

I cannot run the custom tool(PublicResXFileCodeGenerator) for `Resources.zh-CN.resx` but I can run the same tool for `Resources.resx`
Why?

### Second Question

The following code

```cs
Properties.Resources.Culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("zh-CN");
Console.WriteLine(Properties.Resources.HelloWorld);
```

will print "Hello World!" instead of the expected result "你好世界！" as defined in `Resources.zh-CN.resx`
How can I print the expected result?

#### -----Update-----

I solved the above questions by myself but the way I solved it confused me and I have no idea what fixed it.
In my solution I have three projects and the resources are in the library project which is depended by the other two projects. Where I try to print the string is from the console project in this solution.
If I move the resource files to the console project it works well.
However I need the resource files be shared in the library project by the other two.
So, here comes the third question.

### Third Question

Now I wonder why this happens? And how can I access the resource files from other projects in a solution correctly?

Comment: I could see that the "Resources.zh-CN.resx" doesn't have the c# file attached. How you added the "Resources.zh-CN.resx" to the code?

Comment: @SathishGuru File->New->File->Resource Files. I cannot find Resource Files option in Add->New Item. And I cannot generate the c# file using the custom tool, as described in the first question.

Comment: Based on your description, you can refer to [How to use shared resource file between projects in one solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10334095/11507778) to know how to access the resource files from other projects in a solution.