# Share *.resx file between C# and VB.Net projects in the same solution

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

This question is different from other ones (e.g. [How to use shared resource file between projects in one solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995315/how-to-use-shared-resource-file-between-projects-in-one-solution)) because it concerns sharing resx files between projects written in different languages (C# and VB.NET).

**Question:**
I created a resx file "Shared.resx" containing only strings in a VB.NET project. I linked this file as well as its designer.vb file to all other projects and set its modifier to "public". This works well in all VB.NET projects in the solution.

I also have several C# projects in the same solution. Here I can link the *.resx file but not the *.designer.vb file.

My current workaround is to set the access modifier of the resx file in the C# projects (!) to "internal" as this will create a *.designer.cs file.

Is this the correct way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: It's the wrong way. Resources are compiled directly into the DLL. The application language doesn't matter. If you make the resources *public* instead of their default, you can refer to them from other projects. Or you can use a `ResourceManager` class to load resources from an an assembly specified by name.

Comment: I cannot access the resx file in the VB.net project with its access modifier set to public from the C# project.

Comment: Did you read the link? Did you try making the resources public and using them from other projects, the same way you would with any class or property?

Comment: Does your c# project reference the VB-project? As long as all projects are .net the specific language should not matter, it will all be compiled to CIL anyway.  And check the designer.vb file to verify that it actually is public when set to public.

Comment: The `designer` files themselves load the resources and generate properties that the rest of your project uses. By default, those are `internal`, which means they can't be used by other projects. You can make them public, or add an `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute to your project, that specifies which other projects can read Internal properties