# c# error using a linked resource from another project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, embedded-resource

I have a solution which contains 2 projects: Utils and MyProj.
MyProj contains:

1. a folder Resources which contains a txt file: myResource.txt.
2. a resources.resx file to which myResource.txt was added.

Now I want to use this txt file as resource in the Utils project.

1. I've created a Resources folder under the Utils project and added
   myResource.txt as link.
2. I've added resources.resx as link to the Utils project.

This does not seem to work: when I open the resx file under Utils it says that the "resource could not be loaded because the file to which it is linked could not be found".

Thanks,
Li

Comment: Your question was already handled on Stackoverflow:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197029/how-to-have-different-solutions-refer-to-one-resx-file.

Comment: Thx I could not find it myself for some reason. Many thanks for the reference. and sorry for the dup.